# How to refer to the pointer **environ in a user-defined namespace's member function?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, namespaces, g++

```
#include <iostream>

namespace A {
    void func();
}

void  A::func()
{
    extern char **environ;
    std::cout << environ[0] << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
     A::func();
     return 0;
}
```

Like the code above, I just want to use the system-defined pointer `**environ` in `A::func()`, but g++ always says:

```
undefined reference to `A::environ'
```

How can I use the system-defined variable `environ` correctly?

Comment: You'll have to move the declaration of `environ` outside of namespace `A`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
 #include <unistd.h>
```

and environ must be in global scope.

So the code would look like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
extern char **environ;
namespace A {
void func();
}

void  A::func()
{

    std::cout << environ[0] << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
     A::func();
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: But, it doesn't work, at least in my g++. _`undefined reference to `A::environ'`_

Comment: @MM. It should work - make sure `extern char **environ` only appears once, and is outside the namespace.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to declare `environ` at global scope, which is of course where it is defined, rather than within your function.

If you want to be a little cleaner about it and avoid unnecessary use of global variables, you can declare main this way:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[], char* envp[])
```

Then simply pass `envp` to your function.  It will work the same as the global.